# wxWidget - set cell value of a wxGrid object

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I would like to set the value of selected cells in a wxGrid object (below: PuzzleGrid), but my code doesn't work. Any idea why is it wrong? Thanks!

```
void wxkitFrame::OnDrawStarButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
wxArrayInt wxCols, wxRows;
wxCols=PuzzleGrid->GetSelectedCols();
wxRows=PuzzleGrid->GetSelectedRows();
wxString star="*";

for (int i=0; i<wxRows.GetCount(); i++)
{
    int rownum=wxRows[i];
    for (int j=0; j<wxCols.GetCount(); j++)
    {
        int colnum=wxCols[j];
        PuzzleGrid->SetCellValue(rownum,colnum,star);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here as you didn't bother debugging the code yourself, but I think your `wxCols` and `wxRows` variables (these are bad names BTW, don't use `wx` prefix if you want to ensure your identifiers don't conflict with wxWidgets ones) are empty because `GetSelected{Cols,Rows}()` don't return anything unless you had changed the selection mode explicitly using `SetSelectionMode(wxGridSelectRowsOrColumns)`: by default the selection mode is `wxGridSelectCells` meaning that you should iterate over the individual cells and not columns/rows.